# jQuery code that set everything to default value every time I hit save

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a form that has a checkbox; this checkbox when I check it, it disables another form which alternative contact form and set the values in first form which is 
main contact to alternative contact. However, when I uncheck it remove "disable"
and set the values in the alternative form to the default. The problem that I am having with my code (which I provide below) is every time I hit save and the checkbox is unchecked. It set the values that inserted to default which is empty string.

```
$(".AlternativeContactFields").removeAttr("disabled");
$(".AlternativeContactFields").each(function (index, element) {
  if ($(element).is("input")) {
    $(element).val("");
  } else if ($(element).is("select")) {
    $(element).val(1);
  }
});
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please remove the C# tag.

Comment: If I understand the question, the problem is that a checkbox is also an input element.  So, as you erase the value of text input elements, it also erases the caption of radio/checkboxes

Comment: You can call `reset()` on the form to revert it to its original values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#save').click(function() {
    $(".AlternativeContactFields").removeAttr("disabled");
    $(".AlternativeContactFields").each(function (index, element) {
      if ($(element).is("input")) {
        // read the type attribute.
        var type = $(element).attr('type');
        switch(type) {
          case 'checkbox':
          case 'radio':
            // uncheck box
            $(element).prop('checked', false);
            break;
          case 'text':
          default:
            $(element).val("");
            break;
        }  
      } else if ($(element).is("select")) {
        $(element).val(1);
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
<input type="button" value="Save" id="save"/><br/>
<input disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="My checkbox 1" class="AlternativeContactFields"/>My checkbox 1<br/>
<input disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" value="My checkbox 2" class="AlternativeContactFields"/>My checkbox 2<br/>
<input disabled="disabled" type="text" value="My textbox value 1" class="AlternativeContactFields"/><br/>
<input disabled="disabled" type="text" value="My textbox value 2" class="AlternativeContactFields"/><br/>
<select disabled="disabled" class="AlternativeContactFields">
  <option value="0">my Option 0</option>
  <option value="1">my Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">my Option 2</option>
</select>
```